# Is it always necessary to use "is_array()" before a foreach?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I was wondering if it is always necessary to use something like `is_array()` before every `foreach` i do.

In case the variable is not an array, it throws an error.
So i always use:

```
if(is_array($users))   {
    foreach($users as $user){

    }
}
```

What would you recommend me?
Thanks.

Comment: who built the variable `$users`? Did you? Is there any reason to think it might not be an array? What I'm saying is; if you build the variable, you generally know it's type.

Comment: @BerryLangerak **exactly**... see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11156759/561731)

Comment: Who says that this *is* necessary at all?

Comment: Well it should be nice if PHP could providy some `tryforeach` language construct: a `foreach` loop that simply skips the loop of the variable is not of the correct type...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Well if you **know** your code well enough, there should be **no** reason to have to check if it is an array.

Otherwise, if the variable changes type **that** often I would suggest tweaking your code a bit so it does not do that.

Other than that, using that if statement is the way to go.

Comment: Remembering all details of your code is not a very safe way of not having to program defensively. You can't be sure, you can always have a case of the mondays or fridays or any not-so-sharp moment in between and screw up some variable assignment.

Comment: @CodeCaster hence the last part of my answer.

Comment: ... which you ninja'd in during or after I posted my comment. :-P

Comment: @CodeCaster haha I only saw your comment after my supreme ninja skills kicked in :-P

Comment: @CodeCaster In case you have a case of the ~(mon|fri)days~, your testcases would fail. Right? :)

Answer (score 5):

If you're sure that something is an array or otherwise implements Iterable, you obviously don't need the extra `if` condition. If you're not sure, then obviously checking the type will make your code more reliable.

Some hacks I've seen include casting the variable to an array: (array)$users. This is not recommended though, it's better to explicitly check the type.

Also, if this is code inside a function you can use argument typing:

```
function mycode(array $users)
{
    foreach ($users as $user) { }
}
```

When the function is called with the wrong type it will trigger an error.

Comment: More than checking it when it is an array, i check it in case it is a NULL value. So it can not iterate. Then?

Comment: @Steve `is_array(null) == false`?

Comment: Yeah, but i mean. Then you will always have to check it. It is not optional.

Comment: @Steve you've lost me ... if a value is null you can't iterate it, but normally in your own code you would know what value your variables have ... unless you're writing a library that will be used by others, in which case you will want to either have function argument typing or the extra `if`.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming this happens in a function:

```
function doSomethingWithUsers($users)
{
    if(!is_array($users))
    {
        throw new Exception('$users is expected to be an array');
    }

    foreach($users as $user){
        ...
    }
}
```

This way you'll immediately see whenever it's called with the wrong parameters.

Comment: The thing is. It won't be an error. Just that if the array is a null value, it won't execute the code and i will return null.
Then what is the correct way to deal with it? Checking it like i did?

Answer (score 2):

In general, it's better **not to**.

A good general principle in programming is not to hide or ignore errors.

If a variable *should* be an array, it does you no service to specifically ignore the situation if it's not an array.  Instead, it is better for you to be informed of the problem with the built-in error handling.  Otherwise, you're not fixing the problem, just hiding its effects.  This can make debugging subsequent problems difficult.

However, there's a number of assumptions here:

- This is assuming that the variable is supposed to be an array.  If you're using foreach () on it, I assume this to be the case.  If you're running foreach () on something that *might legitimately not be an array* it might be an indication your code may need re-working.
- Your error reporting and/or logging (reporting on a development server, logging on production) needs to be set up correctly in order to benefit from what PHP errors tell you.  Specifically, it's almost never a good idea to ignore PHP warnings - despite being called "warnings" they usually indicate a failure which (in my opinion) should stop execution.

That said, it's not necessarily *wrong* to use an `is_array()` in front of a foreach ().

Answer (score 1):

> What would you recommend me?

Yes it is good idea and such considerations make you a [defensive programmer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming) :)

Comment: If you are *developing for the web* **XOR** _working on a team with other developers_ I personally believe it's crucial to escape & validate / type check all variables.  This should be paired with creating explanatory variable names and other _team oriented_ practices..

Answer (score 0):

It's better for me:

```
foreach (is_array($arr) ? $arr : array() as $key=>$val) {
  //..
}
```